# am using ScratchPadView for iphone app when am taking screenshot on scratchpad i have written some thing but its not showing the content

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, screenshot

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size );
 [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *currentScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

here am unable get the screenshot of updated scratchpad something done on scratchpad but it not showing in my screenshot
![Scratchpad screenshot][1]

Comment: self.bounds.size ..?Where is the Screenshot?

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size );                screenshot is saving to my album     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imgage,nil,nil,nil);      but scratch pad but the roughwork done onthe scratchpad is not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this , if you consider to take a screenshot of `UIView or UIImageView` .

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, 1.0);// Add your view / ScratchPadView whichever you want to take Snap
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    NSData *imgData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```